# Cant figure if TOR is running on my Linux?

Tags: raspberry-pi

I got TOR running on my Raspberry PI mini server for 24 hours.
I use ARM to see how its doing, but the numbers doesnt make sense.
It only downloaded 39 MB and uploaded 17 MB, I would guess the activity will be much larger by this time.

Attached is a screenshot, what do you guys think ?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is to be expected. In the first ~3 days of a new relay's life, it gets very little use. It's said to be in the "unmeasured" phase. In this period your bandwidth is effectively capped while the bandwidth authorities make up their mind about about whether to trust your relay.

The below picture is taken from [Lifecycle of a New Relay](https://blog.torproject.org/blog/lifecycle-of-a-new-relay), and shows the average bandwidth in KB/s against uptime in days. Your relay is currently in the first horizontal phase.

[image]